# How Can I Ignore Unknown Json Properties in Apex

Tags: apex, json

I'm doing a web service call, and parsing the json response into a wrapper object for display on a Visualforce page.

My wrapper object looks like:

```
public class CustomerAddresses {
    public String line1 {get; set;}
    public String line2 {get; set;}
    public String city {get; set;}
    public String state {get; set;}
}
```

My json parser looks like:

```
String fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();                
            if(fieldName == 'addr' && parser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY){
                while(parser.nextToken()!= JsonToken.END_ARRAY){
                    if(parser.getCurrentToken()==JSONToken.START_OBJECT){
                        CustomerAddresses s = (CustomerAddresses)parser.readValueAs(CustomerAddresses.class);
                        customerAddressList.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and the json file looks something like:

```
    {
   "theresponse":{
      "addrs":{
         "addr":[
            {
               "line1":"11562 TEST DR",
               "line2":"ORANGEVILLE",
               "city":"GARDEN GROVE",
               "state":"AZ"
            },
            {
               "line1":"123 TEST BLVD",
               "line2":"TREE HARBOR",
               "city":"FAIRMONT",
               "state":"CA"
            }
         ]
      },
```

Here's my problem, if (in the future) someone adds another attribute to the json file, such as "zip" (see example below), then my class breaks because I can't create an object without the attribute being declared in the CustomerAddresses class. **How can I ignore json attributes that aren't in my class CustomerAddresses?**
Thank you in advance for any help with this!!

Ex: bad json file:

```
        {
   "theresponse":{
      "addrs":{
         "addr":[
            {
               "line1":"11562 TEST DR",
               "line2":"ORANGEVILLE",
               "city":"GARDEN GROVE",
               "state":"AZ",
               "zip":"80001"
        },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for [readValueAs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm#apex_System_JsonParser_readValueAs) says (emphasis mine):

> When deserializing JSON content into an Apex class in any API version,
>   or into an object in API version 35.0 or later, no exception is
>   thrown. When no exception is thrown, this method **ignores extraneous
>   attributes and parses the rest of the JSON content**.

My reading of this is that your code should continue to work when extra JSON attributes are added. But I suggest you create a test case to ensure that the code does what the documentation says.

Comment: Ninja'd by seconds! - I'd also add to double check the version of the apex class being used for parsing as this "silently ignore" behavior is new as of the last two API releases (35 & 36). And for good measure, use the `.readValueAsStrict()` method to throw an exception if you don't desire this silent behavior post API v.35.

Comment: +1, but I'd add that it might be easier to just deserialize using JSON.deserialize.

Comment: @MarkPond Good to flag; the documentation reads like deserializing into an instance of an Apex class doesn't require the API >= 35 but if I was writing the code I'd set the API to >= 35 to be safer.

Comment: @sfdcfox Agreed; not sure why JSONParser gets used so much.

Comment: Good catch Keith. I missed the previous sentence in the documentation and incorrectly assumed what "object" meant. _"When deserializing JSON content into a custom object or an sObject..."_. As for `JSON.deserialize()`, I guess some people just like to do it the hard(er) way. To each their own!

Comment: thank you all!! My class version was actually 36. I feel a little stupid now. When I got the error earlier I made the misassumption that 'extra attributes' were the primary cause of the error I was getting. The primary error was actually that one of address lines (zip) was sometimes being returned in the json as an Integer, and sometimes being returned as a Long. Just tested it, that seems to be the main culprit. Thanks again, I hope others find this useful